Copying or Extending Formula to Excel Cells Vertically
I am trying to apply a formula to determine my max heart rate in percentage based on the actual heart rate (bpm).
My max is 170 and I'd like to see the percentages all the way down to say resting heart rate, or 72bpm.
When I drag the highlighter all the way down, all it does is continue to divide the original cells entered.  But I want it to continue the sequence all the way down.  For example:
Divide a3/a2.
Divide a4/a2.
Divide a5/a2.
enter image description here-My spreadsheet
How do I do this?
Thanks,
Chris
I tried to drag the formula but it only kept dividing the original cells entered in the formula.
my spreadsheet

$ prefix will stop row/column update and in case you can replace = with '=, reorder somehow like transpose (copy / paste row x columns) and replace back '= with = or you can copy formulas as text after 1st replace, update or edit then outside and paste back.

Or you could spill down --> =DROP(A2:A15/$A$2,1) but from the screenshots it looks like you are using Google Sheets is that so?

=A2:A15/MAX(A2:A15) ? That way no matter what row the max value is positioned, it returns the percentage compared to the max value.

Below/here refer.
Include $ signs around the first one (here, cell a2) to ensure it doesn't change:
=a3/$a$2

Drag it down and only the top number in the ratio/% changes, not the bottom one...

Note:
When you're entering the function you can press 'f4' (function 4) button after typing in a2 and the dollar signs automatically toggle. If you're not familiar with this feature, safest bet might just be to manually type in the $ signs. I have linked the spreadsheet used to create all these screenshots - you could try that too and tailor as required.

Here are some more elegant ways to achieve this if you're interested:
Two approaches depending upon preference/situation:

a) First entry not necessarily max:
In this case, divide each value by the max of all such entries:

=A2:A15/MAX(A2:A15)

Note: you don't need to drag this function, you just type it in the first cell (in this case cell B2), after modifying the ranges in col A as req. for your spreadsheet/number of HB entries.
Notice too that in this case you don't need to worry about 'fixing' anything with $ signs as we saw with the 'draggable' version above. Same goes for the next alternative approach...
If this doesn't spill out an array / you get an error, it may because you do not have Office 365 compatible version Excel.  No worries, you can still enter an array, just slightly differently - see here for how.
b) Always divide by first entry (regardless of whether max or not)
If you simply want to take %s of the first entry regardless (or its guarenteed to be the max by default etc..) then you can use the array formula as before:

=A2:A15/A2


Best wishes with your heart measurements.
